# Select values with a more recent year and month when both are stored in different columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

The setup in both tables is that year and month are in two seperate columns as numbers.
I am trying to select the values from one table that do not exists in the other table (so are more recent date wise).

For example: Table1 has values from 2016 until today and Table2 only until end of 2018. So I want to select the values from table 1 for 2019, since those are not yet in table2.

What I have so far:

```
Select * FROM
Table1
WHERE YearNb > 
    (Select top 1 YearNb 
    from Table2
    order by YearNb desc);
```

This gives me all values from Table 1 that have a higher year than table2. Now I have the issue that adding months is not that easy.. I was thinking of maybe combining the two columns in a temp table to an actual date for comparison.

Comment: hi, please provide your full table structure data type and some sample data.

Comment: Slight detour....but choosing datatypes is important. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks for the interesting link. I am still quite new to SQL. Sadly this is a structure setup in the whole company database like this and I am merely an intern. So there is not much I can do about it for now..

Comment: Understand you can't always change things. But the knowledge shared in that post  is something you should keep in mind in situations where you do have that control. Part of your challenge is dealing with a poor decision of datatypes.

Comment: Do you mean Table1 has exactly the same rows as Table2, plus some new rows?

Comment: @Jarlh no, 1 of them is actuals and the other is forecasts. They are later combined in a different table.So it is really just a comparison on the Year and Month columns.

Comment: Then I'd go with @Zhorov's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you may try with next approach. Just generate date values from your year and month columns:

SQL Server 2012+

```
SELECT *
FROM #Table1
WHERE DATEFROMPARTS(Year1, Month1, 1) > (SELECT MAX(DATEFROMPARTS(Year2, Month2, 1)) FROM #Table2)
```

Earlier versions:

```
SELECT *
FROM #Table1
WHERE (Year1 * 100 + Month1) > (SELECT MAX(Year2 * 100 + Month2) FROM #Table2)
```

Comment: this is working nicely, would the same also work on tables where I have weekly data? So having the weeknumber instead of month?

Comment: @Tim Yes, if you have year and week number instead of year and month, the logic is the same.

Comment: thank you! I will play around with it a bit. I see the DATEFROMPARTS function only works with months, but using your earlier version seems to work for weeks!

Comment: @Tim Yes, `DATEFROMPARTS` expects `year`, `month` and `day` as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `NOT EXISTS` :

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table2 t2 WHERE t2.YearNb = t1.YearNb);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can ensure that Table1 has the same data that Table2 has until end of 2018, you can use JOIN to extract data for 2019:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM Table1 t1
    LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.YearNb = t2.YearNb
    WHERE t2.YearNb IS NULL;
```

However, if you have data from Table1 which doesn't have for Table2 until end of 2018, you can add some conditions in the WHERE clause to exclude those data.